# Use of unresolved identifier 'messageLabel'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having this issue:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'messageLabel'

(twice line 84 & 97) and

> Use of unresolved identifier 'metadataObj'

(line 102)

on the next code:

```swift
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  QR Code 2
//
//  Created by Msys on 1/26/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Msys. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDevice class to initialize a device object and provide the video
        // as the media type parameter.
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

        // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
        var error:NSError?

        let input: AnyObject?

        do {
            let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType( AVMediaTypeVideo )
            input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput.init( device: captureDevice )
        } catch {
            if let error = error as NSError?
            {
                print( "<error>", error.code, error.domain, error.localizedDescription )
            }
            return
        }

        if let input = input as! AVCaptureInput? {
            // tutorial should be fine from this point...
        }

        if (error != nil) {
            // If any error occurs, simply log the description of it and don't continue any more.
            print("\(error?.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        // Initialize the captureSession object.
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        // Set the input device on the capture session.
        captureSession?.addInput(input as! AVCaptureInput)

        // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
        let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

        // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
        captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]

        // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
        videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

        // Start video capture.
        captureSession?.startRunning()

        // Initialize QR Code Frame to highlight the QR code
        qrCodeFrameView = UIView()
        qrCodeFrameView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
        qrCodeFrameView?.layer.borderWidth = 2
        view.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView!)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(qrCodeFrameView!)


        func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

            // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
            if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
                qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRectZero
                messageLabel.text = "No QR code is detected"
                return
            }

            // Get the metadata object.
            let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

            if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
                // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
                let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObj as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
                qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject.bounds;

                if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
                    messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
                }
            }
        }

        let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObj as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject.bounds

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var captureSession:AVCaptureSession?
    var videoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var qrCodeFrameView:UIView?


}
```

Comment: Where is messageLabel defined?

Comment: Did you bring/connect a **Referencing Outlet** from **Interface Builder** to your `ViewController`? It appears not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined the messageLabel variable anywhere in your code, so trying to set a property of a undefined variable throws that error.

**EDIT:** Try linking the label from your storyboard to your ViewController and call it messageLabel.

With the metadataObj, you have defined it inside a function, but are attempting to use it outside of that function.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the messageLabel var, u can do it in storyboard or in the code
other option is to remove the lines with the messageLabel